# How to read Translation Matrix from xRef Stream using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I have a PDF from which I want to read the Translation Matrix for a particular Text Annotation. Using iText RUPS I can see that the /AP key have a /N entry that points to an xRef stream

[image]

Looking to the xRef table I can see that the stream holds the Translation Matrix that I am looking for

[image]

The problem is that I am not finding an way to access this information programmatically via PDFBox 3.0.0 (I also tried iText). The closest that I got is using the following code excerpt:

```java
URL file = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("document.pdf");
PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new File(file.toURI()));
System.out.println(document.getDocument().getObjectFromPool(new COSObjectKey(28, 0)).getObject())
```

This code prints the string representing the object and I can see COSStream{363946310} at the end, but couldn't find an way of accessing this content

```
COSDictionary{COSName{Length}:COSInt{189};COSName{BBox}:COSArray{COSFloat{153.0};COSFloat{198.0};COSFloat{459.0};COSFloat{594.0};};COSName{Resources}:COSDictionary{COSName{ExtGState}:COSDictionary{COSName{TRP11}:COSDictionary{COSName{CA}:COSFloat{0.300003};COSName{Type}:COSName{ExtGState};COSName{ca}:1050253822;};};COSName{Font}:COSDictionary{COSName{C2_0}:COSObject{COSNull{}};};COSName{ProcSet}:COSArray{COSName{PDF};COSName{Text};};};COSName{Subtype}:COSName{Form};}**COSStream{363946310}**
```

I've also tried this code:

```
URL file = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("document.pdf");
PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new File(file.toURI()));
 document.getPage(0).getAnnotations().get(0).getAppearance().getNormalAppearance().getAppearanceStream().getMatrix()
```

But this code returns a Translation Matrix that differs from the one I can see in RUPS:

```
[1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
```

Here is the same file analyzed in PDFBox Debugger

[image]

Comment: Please share your file and try looking at it with PDFBox PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thanks for the reply! I edit the post adding same file analyzed through PDFBox PDFDebugger, as for the file I'll need to strip some content out before uploading it

Comment: Oops, when I wrote my comment I hadn't seen that the matrix was there (cut off on my mobile device; I'm now sitting at my desktop). So that's in the top content stream of the appearance stream of the annotation. There can be several or none, it isn't an attribute. You can use `PDFStreamParser` to parse these.

Comment: Thank you very much @TilmanHausherr! PDFStreamParser the missing piece. Also, with your response I was able to search for the use of this class and found this that helped me understand how to use it http://www.java2s.com/example/java-src/pkg/airviewer/textinannotationreplacer-09136.html